# URL Rewrite IIS 7.5 - 403 Forbidden error for aspx asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, http-status-code-403

Ok. I am setting up a website and hosting it for an organization.

I have an asp.net page (....com/sermons.aspx) and I'd like to remove the .aspx file extension so that the web-address is (......com/sermons).

For all the other pages (html/php) I am using URL rewrite rules to remove the extension, however whenever I try to do it for the asp-net page I keep on getting a 403:Forbidden Error.

I have made sure that the sermons.aspx has full read/write control etc.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I am no expert and this, but I'm willing to learn and I appreciate any help that you can provide me.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a folder named 'sermons' on your site, that could explain it. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had a folder with the same name on the server. So I renamed the page name and that seems to have solved the problem :) Thanks to @chris Gessler :D